# Splitting a file by lines into N guaranteed files as evenly as possible using AWK

Tags: unix, csv, awk, split

If I have a file, bigfile.csv which is L+1 lines long (including a header), and my goal is to split this file into N files (say 100) as evenly as possible, appending the header into each of the splits. Assuming that I know how many lines there are in the file, and that how many files it needs to be split into, a priori.

Currently, I already have this code:

```
awk 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} (NR-2)% 100==0 {filename = sprintf("%04d",int((NR-2)/100)+1) ".smallfile.csv"; print h >> filename} {print >> filename}' bigfile.csv
```

While this code works most of the time, there are two failings with this:

1. Unless the number of lines in the original file is exactly divisible by N, there will be N-1 files of ceil(L/N) lines with the last file having significantly less than the other files. This is not as big of a deal, however.
2. In some situations, where if N is big and the ratio between L and N is low, you wouldn't have N guaranteed files. For example, if the original file has 6021 lines to be split into 100 files, you would only end up with 99 files, since each file would have 61 lines.

How would I do this in AWK? Ideally, given the above example, the split for 6021 lines into 100 files would have 21 files with 61 lines and the rest with 60 lines.

I know that you could use split(1) in unix and do it round-robin style, but that changes the sequence of the lines. Later on these lines would be processed distributively and reassembled, so it would be more ideal to keep the same sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid we'll have to resort to...math. Not very complicated math, happily. I envision this:

```
awk -v files=100 'NR == FNR { linecount = FNR; next } FNR == 1 { chunksize = (linecount - 1) / files; h = $0; next } FNR > nextsplit { close(filename); ++chunk; filename = sprintf("%04d.smallfile.csv", chunk); nextsplit = 1 + int(chunksize * chunk + 0.5); print h >> filename } { print >> filename }' bigfile.csv bigfile.csv
```

In order to split the file into even chunks, we have to know how many lines it has before we can start splitting, so this requires two passes -- that is why `bigfile.csv` is mentioned twice.

The awk code is

```
NR == FNR {         # During the first pass: remember the line count.
  linecount = FNR   # I'd like to use ENDFILE for this, but mawk doesn't
                    # know it. Oh well.
  next              # Do nothing else for the first pass.
}
FNR == 1 {          # first line of the second pass:
  chunksize = (linecount - 1) / files  # calculate chunksize
  h = $0                               # remember header.
  next                                 # skip to data
}
FNR > nextsplit {   # When we pass a split point:
  close(filename)   # close previous output file (if any)
  ++chunk           # update chunk counter and build new output file name
  filename = sprintf("%04d.smallfile.csv", chunk)

  # and calculate the next split point. This is very simply
  # chunksize * chunk rounded to the next integer. The rounding is important
  # to ward of floating point rounding errors that might leave us with a
  # one-line file at the end if 1234.9999999 were rounded down to 1234.
  # offset of one because we don't count the header as part of the split data.
  nextsplit = 1 + int(chunksize * chunk + 0.5)

  # Then print the header to the new file
  print h >> filename
}
{ print >> filename } # and print all lines to the file.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I ran your code, I actually ended up with 6021 split files, with the first file having the header, the second having the first line, etc.

Comment: Oh, I get that behavior with mawk but not gawk. Hmm...I'm probably using some non-portable floating point feature, but which? Give me a moment.

Comment: Ah, no: mawk doesn't understand `ENDFILE`. I wasn't expecting that. I'll edit in a workaround. And accomodate the header I forgot the first time around.

Comment: Thanks, that worked correctly. Just one question though. At the beginning of the first second pass, nextsplit hasn't been defined yet. Is it preset to 0? Is that why the FNR>nextsplit evaluate to true?

Comment: "+1" using sprintf AND string concatenation `sprintf("%04d", chunk) ".smallfile.csv"` is kinda odd though - consider just using sprintf instead: `sprintf("%04d.smallfile.csv", chunk)`

Comment: Oh, right. I just cargo-culted that, but it's nicer your way. (edited)

Comment: As `int` always rounds down and `+` is executed after `*` doesn't that make the `+ 0.5` redundant ? great answer BTW :)

Comment: @JID If `chunksize == 10.7` and `chunk == 4`, then `chunksize * chunk == 42.8` (discounting floating point errors), `chunksize * chunk + 0.5 == 43.3` and `int(that) == 43`, where without the `+ 0.5` it would have been `42`. It's a common way to round to the nearest integer rather than down (for positive numbers).

Comment: Ahh right, for some reason i was thinking chunksize would be an int, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a test bigfile
{ echo "header"; seq 6021; } > bigfile.csv

# strip the header
tmp=$(mktemp)
sed 1d bigfile.csv > "$tmp"
header=$( sed 1q bigfile.csv )

# split the file
N=100
split --suffix-length=${#N} --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.csv --number=r/$N $t smallfile.

# add the header to each file
sed -i "1i\\
$header" small*
```

And, examining the results:

```
$ wc -l small*
   62 smallfile.001.csv
   62 smallfile.002.csv
   62 smallfile.003.csv
   62 smallfile.004.csv
   62 smallfile.005.csv
   62 smallfile.006.csv
   62 smallfile.007.csv
   62 smallfile.008.csv
   62 smallfile.009.csv
   62 smallfile.010.csv
   62 smallfile.011.csv
   62 smallfile.012.csv
   62 smallfile.013.csv
   62 smallfile.014.csv
   62 smallfile.015.csv
   62 smallfile.016.csv
   62 smallfile.017.csv
   62 smallfile.018.csv
   62 smallfile.019.csv
   62 smallfile.020.csv
   62 smallfile.021.csv
   61 smallfile.022.csv
   61 smallfile.023.csv
   61 smallfile.024.csv
   61 smallfile.025.csv
   61 smallfile.026.csv
   61 smallfile.027.csv
   61 smallfile.028.csv
   61 smallfile.029.csv
   61 smallfile.030.csv
   61 smallfile.031.csv
   61 smallfile.032.csv
   61 smallfile.033.csv
   61 smallfile.034.csv
   61 smallfile.035.csv
   61 smallfile.036.csv
   61 smallfile.037.csv
   61 smallfile.038.csv
   61 smallfile.039.csv
   61 smallfile.040.csv
   61 smallfile.041.csv
   61 smallfile.042.csv
   61 smallfile.043.csv
   61 smallfile.044.csv
   61 smallfile.045.csv
   61 smallfile.046.csv
   61 smallfile.047.csv
   61 smallfile.048.csv
   61 smallfile.049.csv
   61 smallfile.050.csv
   61 smallfile.051.csv
   61 smallfile.052.csv
   61 smallfile.053.csv
   61 smallfile.054.csv
   61 smallfile.055.csv
   61 smallfile.056.csv
   61 smallfile.057.csv
   61 smallfile.058.csv
   61 smallfile.059.csv
   61 smallfile.060.csv
   61 smallfile.061.csv
   61 smallfile.062.csv
   61 smallfile.063.csv
   61 smallfile.064.csv
   61 smallfile.065.csv
   61 smallfile.066.csv
   61 smallfile.067.csv
   61 smallfile.068.csv
   61 smallfile.069.csv
   61 smallfile.070.csv
   61 smallfile.071.csv
   61 smallfile.072.csv
   61 smallfile.073.csv
   61 smallfile.074.csv
   61 smallfile.075.csv
   61 smallfile.076.csv
   61 smallfile.077.csv
   61 smallfile.078.csv
   61 smallfile.079.csv
   61 smallfile.080.csv
   61 smallfile.081.csv
   61 smallfile.082.csv
   61 smallfile.083.csv
   61 smallfile.084.csv
   61 smallfile.085.csv
   61 smallfile.086.csv
   61 smallfile.087.csv
   61 smallfile.088.csv
   61 smallfile.089.csv
   61 smallfile.090.csv
   61 smallfile.091.csv
   61 smallfile.092.csv
   61 smallfile.093.csv
   61 smallfile.094.csv
   61 smallfile.095.csv
   61 smallfile.096.csv
   61 smallfile.097.csv
   61 smallfile.098.csv
   61 smallfile.099.csv
   61 smallfile.100.csv
 6121 total
```